# How to customize spree views completely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

How can I customize spree views in rails 3.2.11, I want to add sliders everything a e-commerce site have.Please guide me on this.

Can I import spree views to my application rails views ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read this [guides](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html). Everything is explained very clearly.

> Can I import spree views to my application rails views

Yes, as in any other gem. It is the easiest way and explained in "Template Replacements" section of guide.